# How to create cardano address using cardano-wallet API and hd wallet derivation path

Tags: wallet

Developing a wallet service for cardano using `cardano-wallet`api.
Having hard time aligning my existing HD wallet knowledge w/ cardano-wallet.

Need to create an address for an account [index 33] using HD derivation path.
etc. `m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index`
such as `m/1852/1815/11H/1/1/33` where account is `11`, change is `1` and `address_index` is `33`
using [cardano-wallet API](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cardano-wallets purpose is to allow easily manage your funds without getting too deep into certain complexity of deciding how to derive keys and addresses.

to solve it for you there is a [cardano-addresses](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses) project that gives you much greater control over the key derivation paths.

Answer (score 0):

[medium blog on cardano-wallet](https://medium.com/geekculture/cardano-911-wallet-command-line-interface-part-two-982a096c50e2) answers my question.
I've downloaded the latest release from `https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/releases`

Following command creates an address public and private key files `address.prv` and `address.pub`

> cat $KEYS/root.prv 
> | cardano-wallet key child 1852H/1815H/123H/0/0 
> | tee $KEYS/address.prv 
> | cardano-wallet key public --with-chain-code > $KEYS/address.pub

`1852H/1815H/123H/0/0` is derivation path `purpose, coin_type, account_index, role, address_index`

`1825` is purpose cardano network

`1815` is Ada Lovelace's birth year and ADA coin's code

`123H` is account index

`0` is role. `0` is for change, `1` is for staking etc...

`H` means hardened

Following command generates a payment address. from address's public key.

> cat $KEYS/address.pub | cardano-address address payment 
> --network-tag 1 > $KEYS/address.pay